# Converting array of strings to array of integers and inserting them into rows

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I'm trying to insert multiple values into a row, but i'm having a issue where express/postgres are saying that the numbers are strings and not integers. So i'm trying to figure out how to unpack them and at the same time insert them into the DB. Here is what I have so far

```
insert into campgroundfeatures (campgroundid, featureid)
values($1, unnest(array $2)
```

$1 would equal 1 and $2 is grabbing values from checkboxes on the site, so currently its a array like : [ '4', '5', '8', '15' ]

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Converting array of strings to array of integers: let newArray = oldArray.map((value) => Number(value));

Comment: thanks that seemed to do it I believe! :D

Comment: hmmm, i actually get a error from JS now with this. It works in dbeaver but in JS I get a "syntax error at or near $2" :(